# Change the color of input when theres an error on submit click

Tags: html, css

How can i change the color of the input box in red if  there's an error when i hit the SUBMIT button?

```
<form method="post" action="" ">
        <h3>Add users</h3>

        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($error_user) || ($error_taken)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
  <strong>Username: *</strong>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
  <span class="error"><?php echo $error_user; ?></span><br/>
  <span class="error"><?php echo $error_taken; ?></span><br/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($error_name)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <strong>Name: *</strong>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_name; ?></span> <br/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($error_pass)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <strong>Password: *</strong>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" />
    <span class="error"><?php echo $error_pass; ?></span> <br/>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">

</form>
```

Comment: You should give us final html, not php. And what have you tried so far? What will be the errors?

Comment: Does the class 'has-error' not get added when you have an error? Have you done any front end validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple CSS

```
.form-group.has-error input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different CSS options.

First use:

```
.has-error input{
border: 1px solid red;
}
.has-error .error{
color:red;
}
```

Second:

```
.has-error>input{
border: 1px solid red;
}
.has-error>.error{
color:red;
}
```

just apply any of the CSS and you will be fine. The second one will find `input` and class `error` just into the class `has-error`. If there will be another `<div>` covering them then it will not work.

If you want to live check for errors and display it and change colors etc then you have to use `AJAX`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with javascript or jquery sending POST request with ajax

and before that you can create error handling function